# Cypress: no possibility to open the page with I-frame

Tags: iframe, cypress

I am trying to open the page with I-frames:

Additional steps that I have done:

```
1. When I enable "chromeWebSecurity": true, I get the error: Cypress detected a cross-origin error happened on page load: > Blocked a frame with origin  
2. When I disable "chromeWebSecurity": false, I get the error:  Timed out retrying: expected 'chrome-error://chromewebdata/' and it doesn't redirect to the expected page 
3. Updated package.json file: 
      `"scripts": {
          "download-extension": "ced gleekbfjekiniecknbkamfmkohkpodhe extensions/ignore-x-frame-headers" 
        }
        devDependencies": {
           "chrome-ext-downloader": "^1.0.4",
           "cypress": "^5.3.0" 
   }`

4. Updated index.js file:
 `module.exports = (on, config) => {
        on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, args) => {
            console.log(config, browser, args);
            if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
                const ignoreXFrameHeadersExtension = path.join(__dirname, '../extensions/ignore-x-frame-headers');
               args.push(args.push(`--load-extension=${ignoreXFrameHeadersExtension}`));
               args.push("--disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating,CrossSiteDocumentBlockingAlways,IsolateOrigins,site-per-process");}
               return args;
            });
     };`
```

Any ideas on what could be done to fix this issue?

The code:

````
       it('check X login', () => {
         cy.visit(baseUrl);
         cy.title().should('eq', 'Inloggen');
         cy.get(loginButton).click();
         cy.url().should('contain', expectedURL); // the step where the errors appear
      })
  });```
````

Comment: can you add `cy.wait(5000)` after `cy.get(loginButton).click({force: true});` and keep `"chromeWebSecurity": false`. Do you still get the error ? Also add `{force: true}` for click of login button.

Comment: @AlapanDas thank you for the approach but it doesn't work. The chromeWebSecurity was false.